# Move source code files to CodeIgniter folders

Tags: codeigniter

I am starting to work on some incomplete stuff in codeigniter. I had to install codeigniter on my machine. I have the source code files from the previous work, however I am confused how to move these files to CodeIgniter folder to access them as usual and start working on them.

I am not sure which files go to which folder in the CodeIgniter Folders available when downloaded.

Answer (score 0):

[Download and install Codeigniter](http://codeigniter.com/download.php) on your machine first. Check out in which folders the controllers/models/views/configs reside.

Then you will have an idea which files reside where, if you still have some problems take a peek in the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

CodeIgniter have and `system` a `application` folder.

I'd recommend a new download.

I doubt some change was made on `system` folder, so I think you can ignore it from your project and use the new downloaded one

The project is on the `application` and there you have some folders, as mentioned by gopi1410, that you need to take care, maybe there are libraries, models, controllers, configurations files, autoload, etc.

And tell us what it the version of you application. If it is a old version, there will be some problem using the new version `system` folder.